# a orthgonal matrix transpose equal to the matrix itself?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working on a problem that I have to show $det(A^{T}A) = det(R^2)$

From the QR factorization, I have $A^2 = QR^2$, but how does $A^T= A$? I know that $A^{-1} = A^T$ for the orthogonal matrix.

Comment: What is $R$ ? I suspect you are taking some QR decomposition, but there are several competing concepts of QR decompositions for non-square (or non-invertible) matrices, so you should specify what exactly the Q and the R are required to specify.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I suspect $A$ is meant to be square in this context.  We could make sense of this, however, whenever $A$ is $m \times n$ with $m \geq n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From the QR factorization, I have $A^2 = QR^2$,

No you don't. If $A = QR$, then $A^2 = QRQR$, which has no general simplification.

> but how does $A^T= A$?

It doesn't. Even if $A$ isn't symmetric, it has a $QR$ factorization.

---

**Hint:** Note that $Q$ is orthogonal, and that
$$
A^TA = (QR)^TQR = R^TQ^TQR = R^T(Q^TQ)R
$$
now, remember the properties of the determinant.

Comment: How'd you get $R^TR = R^2$

Comment: @Yangfan I didn't.  But note that
$$
\det(R^TR) = \det(R^T)\det(R) = \det(R)^2 = \det(R^2)
$$

Answer (score 0):

$ $det$(A^2) = ($det$(A))^2 = $det$(A^T) \cdot $det$(A)$

Since $Q$ is orthogonal, $Q^TQ = I,$ so that we have $|$det$ Q| = 1.$

So we have,
det$(A^2) = $det$ (QR^2) \geq 0, $det$(QR^2) = $det$(R^2) \geq 0$

We must have det$ Q = 1$ and therefore,
$ $det$(A^TA) = $det$(R^2).$